# How to extend laravel logger?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, monolog

I have created different files for different level of logging e.g Log::info, Log::error etc. Now I also want to send a message to slack only if an error comes. I have done this too by writing following code in `app/bootstrap.php`

```
$app->configureMonologUsing( function($monolog) {
    $slackHandler = new Monolog\Handler\SlackHandler(env('SLACK_TOKEN'), env('SLACK_CHANNEL'), 'Monolog', true, null, Monolog\Logger::ERROR);
    $monolog->pushHandler($slackHandler);
});
```

but it has overrided the default logger and now only slack logger is working and no logs are adding in storage/logs/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are pretty vague on what exactly this does but it looks like `configureMonologUsing` configures Monolog to use only the handlers which you specifically add to it.  This means the handlers (I believe `StreamHandler`) which Laravel sets up to log to the laravel.log file are never added.

I'd recommend not using that and dropping this code into your `AppServiceProvider` which will add the new handler while keeping all the default handlers Laravel likes to add...

```
$monolog = \Log::getMonolog();
$slackHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\SlackHandler(env('SLACK_TOKEN'), env('SLACK_CHANNEL'), 'Monolog', true, null, Monolog\Logger::ERROR);
$monolog->pushHandler($slackHandler);
```